# Blender viewport looks askew with mirrored object

Tags: blender, viewport

[blender viewport startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPZXm.png)
[blender viewport with cube moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsUX8.png)
Should I reset the settings? Adjust? This is the start up screen. I uploaded the update and Windows(r) will not give unaffected viewport. My MacBook works fine, what is the issue?

I uploaded the update, I checked and reset the settings and adjusted settings on interface.